# how pass value from select option to other select option in other form

Tags: php, html, forms, select, post

I want to move data from one form to another form with similar inputs in diferent pages, as I do to make the select option to acquire the same value when I submit form1 and form2 sees.

```
<form action="form2.html" method="post">
<select name="selection" >
  <option value="" selected="selected">select one</option>
  <option value="1" >one</option>
  <option value="2" >two</option>
  <option value="3" >three</option>
</select>
```

i need to get this value in the second form "form2.html"

how i can do this?

thanks !!

Comment: Well you can't because `form2` is a html page

Comment: @Daan How about using AJAX to save it in DB?

Comment: You need to make it `form2.php`. Then in that script, you can use `$_POST['selection']` to set the default option in its form.

Comment: you can create form2.php  and $_POST get select option value

Comment: @odedta Possible but you'll need 2 ajax request on `form1.html` to insert to db and on `form2.html` to get the value.

Comment: @Daan Indeed you do.

Comment: i do this forms for use them in wordpress page, there is php page but how i can do? you know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action page is necessarily a server page. You have to set the second page say, as form2.php. The data you submit here will go to the form2.php as a post value. It will be something like this :

```
<form action="form_submit.php" method="post">
<select name="selection2" >

 <option value="1" <?php if($_POST['selection'] =="1"){echo "selected='selected'";}?> >one</option>
 <option value="2" <?php if($_POST['selection'] =="2"){echo "selected='selected'";}?>>two</option>
 <option value="3" <?php if($_POST['selection'] =="3"){echo "selected='selected'";}?>>three</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Thus you can get the value in the previous value selected in your new form. Otherwise you may use session to store the value temporarily.

Comment: i use your code thank very much, but the select return in the same position but without de text ...

Comment: Thank you so much. This is for the second form code. Your form 1 is correct but the action page file extension. 
The text will come in the input if remove the first option statement under the select tag in the second form. I just mistakenly forgot to remove it from there. Sorry. Now I am trying edit it once more to remove that line.

Comment: sorry but don't understand, what is the first input option i need remove?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a trivial answer, you could set a $_SESSION variable, save in cookie, save in database and then SELECT that data on the next page using the appropriate method.